# mongodb ignores dbPath parameter?

Tags: mongodb

I installed Mongodb latest (4.0)  as a service on Windows 10
It seems like its ignoring the mongod.cfg file in the bin directory

```
C:\MongoDB4.0\bin\mongod.cfg
# Where and how to store data.
 storage:
     dbPath: C:\MongoDB4.0\data
```

The service will not start,
When I start it from CMD like:

```
c:\MongoDB4.0\bin>mongod.exe
```

This is its output: (see dbpath=c:\data\db)

```
Log:  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
Log:  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=7104 port=27017 dbpath=c:\data\db\ 64-bit host=Win10-Pc
Log:  [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2
Log:  [initandlisten] db version v4.0.2
Log:  [initandlisten] git version: fc1573ba18aee42f97a3bb13b67af7d837826b47
```

I see that the service gets the configuration as a parameter

C:\MongoDB4.0\bin\mongod.exe --config "C:\MongoDB4.0\bin\mongod.cfg" --service

[image: Server Prop]

Answer (score 2):

The `--service` option is used to create the initial service definition, and should generally not be required if you are using a MongoDB 4.0+ installer (which includes this step during installation).

To manage the MongoDB service from the command line you need to use [`net start MongoDB`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#start-mdb-edition-as-a-windows-service) and [`net stop MongoDB`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#stop-mdb-edition-as-a-windows-service).

> c:\MongoDB4.0\bin>mongod.exe

If you run `mongod.exe` without any parameters the default values will be used (such as `c:\data\db` for the `dbPath`). The server binary does not currently have a default location for a configuration file.

There's a relevant feature request to watch/upvote in the MongoDB issue tracker: [SERVER-36150: Improved Default Config File Handling](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-36150).

Comment: Thank you for the answer Stennie, but i dont get how is this related to dbPath

Comment: @user648026 You mention that the `dbPath` in your config file is being ignored when you start from the command line with `mongod.exe`. That is the expected behaviour: there is currently no default config file path so you'd have to invoke via "C:\MongoDB4.0\bin\mongod.exe --config "C:\MongoDB4.0\bin\mongod.cfg" if you want to use the configuration file in the service definition. Since you are trying to troubleshoot your service configuration, you should use `net start MongoDB` to manage from the command line. If the service isn't starting, there should be more info in the MongoDB log file.